# Python-daemon: keep logging

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that logs a bit of data to disk:

`logging.basicConfig(filename='davis-debug.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(filename='davis-error.log',level=logging.ERROR)
logging.basicConfig(filename='davis-error.log',level=logging.WARNING)
logging.basicConfig(filename='davis-error.log',level=logging.CRITICAL)`

When i use python-daemon like this, the logging stops.

```
try:
  with daemon.DaemonContext():
  station = VantageProStation()
  station.run()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  logging.critical('Stopping user aborted with CTRL+C')
pass
```

I have tried file_preserve, but logging.basicConfig does not return a stream.
Also i cannot pass several streams using files_preserve..?
I afcourse want my logging to continue, i tried to put the log definion inside my class **init** that did not help either.

Comment: excepting a KeyboardInterrupt from a daemon is ... strage ?

Comment: Yes, im still in the developement stage, just for testing :)

Answer (score 7):

What about configuring your logger inside your daemon ? This works for me :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import daemon
import logging
import logging.handlers
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def time_logging_daemon():
    logger = logging.getLogger('time_logging_daemon')
    logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log'))
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    while True:
        logger.info(datetime.now())
        sleep(1)

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    time_logging_daemon()
```

Comment: This fixes so many little quirks with DaemonContext.  This gem just solved a bug I've had with using it and logging for years.  A bug I could ignore but always knew was there.  Just "setup logging" after you have the DaemonContext.

Answer (score 1):

The daemon context closes all file handlers to be "well behaved daemon" except the ones specified in the `files_preserve`.  You were in the right direction.

There is a way to get the file handler from `logging` but I suggest that you create the file logger explicitly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import daemon
import logging
import logging.handlers
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

logging.basicConfig()

file_logger = logging.FileHandler("/tmp/aaa.log", "w")

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(file_logger)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

with daemon.DaemonContext(files_preserve=[file_logger.stream.fileno()]):
    while True:
        logger.info(datetime.now())
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: technically the above is doable, but I suggest that you create the logger within the Daemon Context.