# How to find out why code failed within python-daemon?

Tags: python, python-daemon

This is how I run the daemon:

```
        import daemon
        logger = logging.getLogger('time_logging_daemon')
        handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(
            facility=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_DAEMON, address="/dev/log")
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.info("Before")
        with daemon.DaemonContext():
            logger.info("Before daemonizing.")
            try:
                bot.start()
            except:
                logger.info("crashed")
```

Unfortunately all I get in the logs is this:

> Apr  3 22:33:06 mybot Before daemonizing.

It doesn't seem to be crashing, and I can see it in `ps aux | grep python`.
But the code just doesn't function as its supposed to be. How can errors be thrown and captured, so I can see if anything isn't right?

Comment: Try logging the [exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191830/best-way-to-log-a-python-exception); ```logger.exception```. Also, how is 'bot' being defined? Maybe you can try logging in the bot, or raising exceptions from that object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674733/python-daemon-keep-logging

Comment: Thanks both solutions were helpful.  Especially defining the logger inside Daemon context was the key.